# clean way to handle button css attributes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some buttons that I make visible at the time I make my graph visible.
I also put a line through the text depending on the dataset visibility status.
Is there a way to pass an argument to the jquery `$()` so that I can handle this logix in a neat `for` loop?

```
if (!this.drawnAlready) {
        //button subscription
        $('#ds0').css("visibility", "visible");
        $('#ds0').click( function(){
            chartTest.data.datasets[0].hidden = !chartTest.data.datasets[0].hidden;
            chartTest.update();
            $('#ds0').css("text-decoration", chartTest.data.datasets[0].hidden ? "line-through" : "none");
        });
        $('#ds1').css("visibility", "visible");
        $('#ds1').click( function(){
            chartTest.data.datasets[1].hidden = !chartTest.data.datasets[1].hidden;
            chartTest.update();
            $('#ds1').css("text-decoration", chartTest.data.datasets[1].hidden ? "line-through" : "none");
        });
        $('#ds2').css("visibility", "visible");
        $('#ds2').click( function(){
            chartTest.data.datasets[2].hidden = !chartTest.data.datasets[2].hidden;
            chartTest.update();
            $('#ds1').css("text-decoration", chartTest.data.datasets[2].hidden ? "line-through" : "none");
        });
        $('#ds3').css("visibility", "visible");
        $('#ds3').click( function(){
            chartTest.data.datasets[3].hidden = !chartTest.data.datasets[3].hidden;
            chartTest.update();
            $('#ds3').css("text-decoration", chartTest.data.datasets[3].hidden ? "line-through" : "none");
        });
}
```

In the example I show that I do it for three buttons for code clarity, but in my code there are quite a lot of buttons so the code seems clearly improvable :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeating code. So, just write a method that does the repeating part of your code.

For example:

```
function doThings(i)
{
  const elementId = '#ds'+i;
  $(elementId).css("visibility", "visible");
        $(elementId).click( function(){
            chartTest.data.datasets[i].hidden = !chartTest.data.datasets[i].hidden;
            chartTest.update();
            $(elementId).css("text-decoration", chartTest.data.datasets[i].hidden ? "line-through" : "none");
        });
}
```

Then you just need to call this function multiple times.
For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach( i => doThings(i))
```

Answer (score 2):

Give all your #ds0/#ds1/etc the same `class="ds"`, also give them a `data-datasetid="0"` to replace the #ds0 etc

```
<button class="ds" data-datasetid="0">toggle data set 0</button>
<button class="ds" data-datasetid="1">toggle data set 1</button>
```

then replace your code with:

```
if (!this.drawnAlready) {
    $('.ds').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('.ds').click(function() {
        var dataset = $(this).data("datasetid");
        chartTest.data.datasets[dataset].hidden = !chartTest.data.datasets[dataset].hidden;
        chartTest.update();
        $(this).css("text-decoration", chartTest.data.datasets[dataset].hidden ? "line-through" : "none");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had in mind to exatract the funtionality to a `for` loop, so I did not even consider what you are propesing in your answer. However it works and it has been very helpful, so upvoted and thank you

Comment: @rustyBucketBay just FYI this is by far the better approach of the two given. Using this pattern means that the logic is infinitely extensible without needing to update an ugly array to loop over.